# Expandable user card causes hats to flash on then off again

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016, winter-bash, user-card

I know it is essentially over but just saw this so thought I'd post it.

When you hover over a user and the expandable user card shows up, the hat is shown briefly and then disappears again. Note it does happen on the editors one my recorder just missed it for some reason.

[image: Hats Bug]

Comment: In 3 days or so the problem will be fixed ;)

Comment: If I read you correctly the issue you are reporting is that, after the expansion, the hat is briefly visible but then it remains off *permanently*. I'm unable to reproduce this behavior on Chrome 55. Here, the hat flashes off and then back on, and it remains on.

Comment: I like that black mad-hatter thing I have going on in the screenshot. (Or is it more chimney-sweep?)

Comment: @honk that's a massive speed up from the normal 6-8 weeks. How are they supposed to do that?:P

Comment: @CodyGray I think that's the IE problem that was reported before

Comment: @Louis that is the issue I am reporting, I am on IE so that could be what is causing iy

Comment: @Glorfindel: Actually the problem exists since 10 weeks. Just nobody noticed. So, they are actually a bit late ;)

Comment: @Louis I am on Windows 10 Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 m and I can reproduce it

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I see. By the way, the lone downvote is not mine. I've got enough experience testing code on multiple browsers to know that saying "I cannot reproduce it with browser X" is not necessarily the final word.

Comment: @Louis Its okay probably people downvoting because they see no point in fixing it

Comment: @honk it will be fixed in 3 days, but will come back in ~ 333 days ;)